Migration from ffmpeg2.6.8 to ffmpeg5.1.6
Older version of ffmpeg2.6.1, API av_interleaved_write_frame() updated the o/p file very quickly. but latest ffmpeg5.1.6 does not due to optimisation done in this version.How  to achieve fast writing in this version into o/p file
Thanks for the help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am working on an RTSP-based recording system that writes video streams to an output file using FFmpeg. Previously, we used FFmpeg 2.6.1, where the API av_interleaved_write_frame() updated the output file on disk very quickly. However, after upgrading to FFmpeg 5.1.6, we observed that writing to the output file is noticeably slower.

Our application has a monitoring thread that checks the output file every 4 seconds. It performs retries (up to 3) to validate the recording by inspecting:
File size (expects incremental growth)
File MIME type
If no substantial file size increment or MIME validation is detected, the system assumes a recording failure and throws an error.
During low-packet scenarios (e.g., at night when no night-vision camera is active), very few RTSP packets are sent. This exacerbates the delayed writing issue in FFmpeg 5.1.6, causing false negatives in our monitoring logic.

my application does not use any codec, it direclty dump the av packets to o/p file TIME.avi

Your question feels like a "stream of consciousness" and is not organized in a way that makes sense reading it. Also, if you have more info to add, use the EDIT button and add it to the question. Comments are just that: comments. They are not the best place to add more information. Take some time to edit your post to clarify the context, the situation, what you're trying to do, what you have done, the outcome, how that fails to meet your requirements, etc. Try to make each sentence meaningful and clear on its own and within the context of the entire question.
